# JSONValue failed. org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character (3c)\"

Tags: ios

```
   {
    created = "2017-04-17T12:11:15.000Z";
    end =     {
        date = "2017-04-10";
    };
    start =     {
        date = "2017-04-10";
    };
    status = confirmed;
    updated = "2017-04-17T12:11:15.000Z";
    "user_email" = "frejun.testing1@gmail.com";
}
```

this is my posted parameters..how to parse out the error i have sent this parameters but getting the response as

> JSONValue failed. org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3
>   \"Unrecognised leading character (3c)\"

Comment: Did your using swift? Could you check with your server team. also check response code.

Comment: Check your JSON format, use : instead of =

Comment: how it is possible to use : instead of = in making the json object??

Comment: i am using objective c